# Windows 7 icon recovery

Tags: windows, themes

I have installed a Alienware skin for my computer but while it was installing I closed it before it created a uninstaller and I can't uninstall it through control panel. I have tried  to refresh the `IconCache.db` but it didn't work.

How I can get my icons back to normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Click Start button then type `cmd.exe` and right click on it, select `Run as administrator`
2.Type **sfc /scannow** as mentioned below:

> C:\Windows\System32>sfc /scannow

let it run... and when it says it has repaired some files, reboot. Now, all the icon will be fixed. I had the same issue with my pc, and sfc repaired it. *(It fixed the problem left by Mac transformation pack , and also alienware pack)*

Because skin packs modifies the `DLL` files , *IconCache.db* won't hold the skinning data's resources. Yes, it's resources, *alienware* skin package modifies the OS resources that is `dll` and `exe`. That's why doing `sfc` is must. "sfc" is the built-in System File Checker tool that checks the integrity of all windows resources with `winsxs` directory, and restore the original resource files.

**Alternative method:**

Install the same *alienware* skin once again, and let it run, and reboot, and now you should have the uninstaller from control panel, so that you can uninstall as usual.

If you have a system restore point before skin installation, then, restoring the system to that restore point also bring back all the icons

Answer (score -1):

I have faced same issue and tried many solutions but they could not worked, so here is one more solution which i have used to fix this issue is you can upgrade your window by using boot cd or pen drive, it will not make any changes in your previous files or settings. All the changes of your windows will remain same.